# Question about proof that an interval of rationals isn't a null set

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $X=\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$, with $a<b$. This set isn't a null set
>   because if it were, then given $\epsilon<b-a$, there would be a
>   partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that the sum of the lenghts of the
>   intervals of $P$ containing points of $X$ would be $< \epsilon$. Well,
>   the sum of lenghts of all the intervals of $P$ is $b-a$, therefore
>   some intervals of $P$ wouldn't contain points of $X$, that is,
>   rational numbers, which is an absurd.

I didn't understand this proof. I can imagine open sets covering $[a,b]$ and all of them would have rationals contained in it, and their sum is $<\epsilon$. What am I not getting?

Comment: Does "null set" mean empty, or Lebesgue measure $0$? Because if the latter, the claim is false, and in fact $\mathbb{Q}$ is null.

Comment: Following up on AJY's comment, what is this "proof" from?

Comment: The error in this ‘proof’ is the claim that the sum of the lengths of the intervals is necessarily $b-a$: this simply isn’t true. If we index $\Bbb Q\cap[a,b]$ as $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ and put an open interval of length $\frac1{2^{n+2}}$ around $q_n$, the sum of the lengths of the intervals is $\sum_{k\ge 2}\frac1{2^k}=\frac12$. Cut all of the lengths in half, and the sum is $\frac14$. Keep doing this, and you can make it as small as you please.

Comment: @AJY I don't know how to translate it, but the definition is: a set has 'null content' when for all $\epsilon>0$ it's possible to obtain a finite collection of intervals $I_1, \cdots, I_k$ such that $X\subset I_1\cup \cdots \cup I_k$ and the sum of the lengths of the intervals is $<\epsilon$

Comment: The definition that @GuerlandoOCs gave is also known as a "negligible set," which is dual to the notion of a "contented set." The only context I've seen these terms pop up in is advanced calculus books that want to rigorously develop multiple integrals without measure theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two relevant notions of a "small" set of reals.

The first is measure:

> A set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has *measure zero* (or *is null*) if $\forall\epsilon>0$, there is a family of open intervals $U_i$ ($i\in I$) such that $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i\supseteq X$ and $\sum_{i\in I}\vert U_i\vert<\epsilon$ (where "$\vert U_i\vert$" denotes the *length* of $U_i$, not the cardinality).

Under this definition, the rationals and their subsets - and every countable set, more generally - is indeed null. For suppose $X=\{a_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then for $\epsilon>0$, let $U_i=(a_i-2^{-i-17}, a_i+2^{-i-17})$.

However, note that this requires the family of open intervals to be infinite. If we restrict (as does the definition you mention in the comments) to *finite* families, we get a very different notion:

> A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is *negligible* (I think "has null content" is misleading here) if $\forall\epsilon>0$, there is a **finite** family of open intervals $U_i$ ($i\in I$) such that $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i\supseteq X$ and $\sum_{i\in I}\vert U_i\vert<\epsilon$ (where again "$\vert U_i\vert$" denotes the *length* of $U_i$, not the cardinality).

Under this definition, countable sets need no longer be "small!" Indeed, $\mathbb{Q}$ and sets of the form $\mathbb{Q}\cap [a, b]$ for $a<b$ are not negligible. The proof is by induction: we show by induction on $n$ that any cover of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[a, b]$ by at most $n$ many open intervals has total length at least $b-a$, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

That said, the proof you cite is terribly sloppy and unclear, and it skips over enough detail that I would say it is not correct.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that "not negligible" doesn't necessarily mean "contented." I'm a little rusty, but I think there's a theorem that says a bounded set $S$ is contented if and only if the boundary $\partial S$ is negligible. Since $\partial(\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]) = [a,b]$, which is not negligible, $\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$ is not contented. It's pathological in this context in much the same way not all sets are Lebesgue measurable, but we have to do a lot less work to produce such a set since contentedness is much more restrictive than Lebesgue measurability.